# Solving a differential equation (Reduction of order)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi so I have this question here:

Find the general solution to the equation for $y=y(x)$,

$$y''-2y'+y=\frac{e^x}{(x-1)^2}$$
by using reduction of order.

The problem is that, for reduction of order, I need one of the solutions.

I already have the homogeneous equation solved which is $yh(x)=c_1e^x+c_2xe^x$.

How am I just supposed to "guess" one of the solutions? Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the basic formula: $(a-b)^{2}=a^{2}-2ab+b^{2}$.

Let
\begin{equation*}
z=y'-y
\end{equation*}
so that
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dz}{dx}-z=y''-y'-y'+y=y''-2y'+y
\end{equation*}
Then solve the first order differential equation
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dz}{dx}-z=\frac{e^{x}}{(x-1)^{2}}
\end{equation*}
by using integration factor method.

Answer (score 0):

You need one of the homogeneous solutions. So set $y(x)=e^{x}u(x)$ and find
$$
u''=\frac1{(x-1)^2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y''-2y'+y=\frac{e^x}{(x-1)^2}$$
You van guess that $e^x$ is a solution than try reduction of order with $y=e^xv(x)$